# Div not scrolling can only use scrollbar

Tags: html, css, scroll

Hello I am trying to make a div scrollable with mouse wheel but its only working with the scroll bar right now the page is http://154.16.127.140/agar/indexBETA.html Please help me ! Ps its the Server Selection div with all the servers and the blue scroll bar.

Answer (score 0):

Here there is an easy example: [DIV with wheel scrollable content](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex17/jquerycustomscrollbar/index.htm)
If you can't apply let me know I will try to add it in your page.

I try my own suggestion on your page and does not work. Probably as you have many JS some doesn't work together. I try with a page without other JS and it works.

Comment: Yeah if you could try that would be awesome I can't get it to work I must be doing something dumb.

Comment: Sure just let me find some time... I will post here when done with all the steps

Comment: Hi, It seams I can't see anymore your file at http://154.16.127.140/agar/indexBETA.html ?

Comment: Yes sorry I have moved it from indexBeta.html to index.html so just go to http://154.16.127.140/agar/ same thing :)

Comment: You have a function that cover everything (so even if I add a div just after <body> or before </body> I cannot see it) so probably that avoid the mouse over (and wheel) to be detected.